# Mortgage company sent full name, SSN, DOB, and address over email

Tags: email, identity-theft

Just as I said in the title. My mortgage company sent me a document I need to sign via unencrypted email and unfortunately it was pre-filled with my full name, SSN, DOB, and home address. I'm very upset about this and will be shopping around for another company.

I was also wondering, is this even legal? If a malicious individual came across the document there's everything they need to steal my identity and email is not end-to-end encrypted.

Jurisdiction: Arizona, United States

Comment: How do you know the email communication was unencrypted? Nowadays most email providers and clients support TLS which means there is no practical way for a man-in-the-middle to see your email contents.

Comment: In my experience, if you know how to read email headers you can tell if it was encrypted in transit or not.

Comment: @Greendrake  you are talking about encryption at the delivery point.  It doesn't mean it was encrypted in transit.  The old standard that you shouldn't put anything in an email that you wouldn't put on a postcard still applies.  A "postman" can still see whatever you are sending.  And it will be stored unencrypted (effectively) forever in backups.

Comment: @grovkin Nah, I'm talking about encryption in transit. If both the sender and receiver MTAs support TLS (which is already norm these days) then no "postman" can see anything.

Comment: @Greendrake how do they generate a webmail page if they don't have access to the content of the emails?

Comment: @grovkin Email providers certainly do have access to the content. There are 3 legs of encryption: sender -> (1) -> sender's email provider -> (2) -> recipient's email provider -> (3) -> recipient. All the 4 parties can see the content, but noone else can. I reckon the OP does not position his email provider as "malicious individual".

Comment: @Greendrake there is an easy thought experiment to see if they do or do not.  Would they continue using the same provider if the provider required giving them a social security number to continue providing the service.

Comment: @grovkin I don't see how that "thought experiment" is relevant here. OP's email provider did not ask for SSN. Mortgage company sent it. At the end of the day, email providers bear duty of confidentiality to customers. If they breach it, that is a separate question, not that OP asked.

Comment: @Greendrake I don't believe any such duty exists and even if it did, it would still not be any more secure than a postman's duty of confidentiality to the postal service's customers.  It doesn't create any sort of technical impossibility of the content of the communication being leaked.  Contractual?  Maybe, but almost certainly unenforceable.  Technical? No.  Also, I don't see why the thought experiment "doesn't apply."  Either they consider the provider to be trustworthy enough to know their SSN or they don't.  The thought experiment would reveal that.